# Python Plotly Line Chart with a Dataframe: Wrong scale on the y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, linechart

I try to create a line chart with plotly out of a dataframe. Sounds easy, but I'm facing two isseus:

1. The y-axis is scaled wrong. As you can see it is not order from lowest price to highest price. How can I change the order starting from the lowest to the highest price to get a "regular time-series chart"?
2. How can I change the scale from the x-axis to see every single day instead of weeks?

Code:

```
response = requests.get(url) 

data = response.json() 
data1 = data['data']
rates = data1['rates']
rates_dic = rates.items() 

df = pd.DataFrame(rates_dic) 
df[1] = [x[symbol] for x in df[1]]
df.rename(columns = {0:'Date', 1:'Price'}, inplace=True)
df.Price = 1 / df.Price # Alle Rohstoffpreise müssen mit 1 dividiert werden
df['Price'] = df['Price'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Dataframe:

```
Date    Price
29  2022-10-13  $405.00
28  2022-10-12  $386.50
27  2022-10-11  $385.80
26  2022-10-10  $385.80
25  2022-10-09  $385.80
24  2022-10-08  $385.00
23  2022-10-07  $396.25
22  2022-10-06  $404.00
21  2022-10-05  $399.00
20  2022-10-04  $399.00
19  2022-10-03  $433.70
18  2022-10-02  $433.70
17  2022-10-01  $436.00
16  2022-09-30  $436.00
15  2022-09-29  $435.65
14  2022-09-28  $435.65
13  2022-09-27  $435.65
12  2022-09-26  $435.65
11  2022-09-25  $435.65
10  2022-09-24  $435.65
9   2022-09-23  $444.50
8   2022-09-22  $440.00
7   2022-09-21  $439.05
6   2022-09-20  $439.00
5   2022-09-19  $445.50
4   2022-09-18  $445.50
3   2022-09-17  $445.50
2   2022-09-16  $444.20
1   2022-09-15  $439.35
0   2022-09-14  $438.00
```

Creating a line chart with plotly:

```
line_chart = px.line(
            df,
            x = "Date",
            y = "Price",
            title = "Commodity Prices of the last 30 days"
            )
line_chart.show()
```

[Output Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KvtT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
line_chart = px.line(
            df,
            x = "Date",
            y = "Price",
            title = "Commodity Price from the last 30 days in $/t"
            )
line_chart.update_xaxes(type='date')
line_chart.update_yaxes(type='linear')
line_chart.update_yaxes(tickprefix="$")
line_chart.update_xaxes(
dtick="D1",
tickformat="%d.%m.%Y")
line_chart.layout.width=1000
line_chart.layout.height=500
line_chart.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppjf2.png)